# Space between two Links in LinkBar

Tags: apache-flex

I had display in link as follows. Three Links on left hand side ,two links on right hand Side and in between Some space has to be there. Please suggest how to do this.

I have an idea's please suggest which is possible and the technical difficulties.
For three Links i thought to put LinkBar and for the left hand side i thought two apply two LinkButton .Below the links I will place a canvas in that I will add viewstack for the LinkBar and VBox for the LinkButton when it is clicked.

Regards
Zulu

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is to put the LinkBars in a container with absolute positioning and set the left and right properties of the LinkBars to "0" like so:

```
<s:Group width="500">
    <mx:LinkBar left="0">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <fx:String>Link 1</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Link 2</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Link 3</fx:String>
        </mx:dataProvider>  
    </mx:LinkBar>
    <mx:LinkBar right="0">
        <mx:dataProvider>
            <fx:String>Link 1</fx:String>
            <fx:String>Link 2</fx:String>
        </mx:dataProvider>  
    </mx:LinkBar>
</s:Group>
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but i am using flex 3. since this is an web application i have to use width in percentage not in pixel. I have a doubt on the above is that possible that both linkbar can share the same view stack.